# Dipole moment in cylindrical symmetry

Tags: electromagnetism

So I am trying to find the dipole moment for an uncharged sphere in an electric potential, and I am stuck in the following step:

$\vec p = \int_V \rho_{density}(\vec r')\vec r' dV'$

Since we are having cylindrical symmetry, I am concerned only with the last term:

$\vec p_z = \int_V \rho_{density}(\vec r')z' dV'$.

The integral boundaries are : $0-2\pi$ for $\phi$, -R and R for z, and $0 - R$ for $\rho$.

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to express the volume in cylindrical coordinates accordingly. I know that the volume element in cylindrical coordinates ($\rho,\phi,z)$ is:

$dV=\rho dzd\phi d\rho$

But this gives me zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your integral boundaries are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using cylindrical units for a spherical surface gets complicated.
Just use $z=r\cos\theta$ in spherical coordinates.